# ¿Cómo alinear mis columnas?

Tags: bootstrap

```
<b> <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="fecha"><span class="numero">15</span>&nbsp;<span class="mes">JULIO</span></div>
        <div class="texto">
            <p>Cronograma de matr&iacute;culas</p>
            <span>Fecha de matr&iacute;culas: 15 de julio al 30 de agosto (ordinarias)</span><span><br />1 de septiembre al 30 de septiembre (extraordinarias)</span><span><br /><br /></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <h4>Kinder</h4>
    <p>Nacidos entre el 1/09/2012 y el 31/12/2013&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col5 verde push-down">
        <h3>Requisitos</h3>
        <p>C&eacute;dula de ciudadan&iacute;a</p>
        <span>The Happy Room <br />Mrs Linda</span> <span class="hora">Lunch &amp; Recess <br /> 11:30 AM - 00:30 PM</span></div>
    <div class="col5 cafe align-center">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <p>Donec iaculis</p>
        <span>The Happy Room <br />Mrs Linda</span> <span class="hora">Lunch &amp; Recess <br /> 11:30 AM - 00:30 PM</span></div>
    <div class="col5 amarillo align-center">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <p>Donec iaculis</p>
        <span>The Happy Room <br />Mrs Linda</span> <span class="hora">Lunch &amp; Recess <br /> 11:30 AM - 00:30 PM</span></div>
    <div class="col5 verde align-center">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <p>Donec iaculis</p>
        <span>The Happy Room <br />Mrs Linda</span> <span class="hora">Lunch &amp; Recess <br /> 11:30 AM - 00:30 PM</span></div>
</div></b>
```

Por que mis columnas no se despliegan en linea? al introducir el texto se movieron.

Answer (score 1):

La clase que se usa para grillas en Bootstrap es `col-sm-5` (no `col5` que yo sepa), aunque en realidad deberias poner `col-sm-3` para que las cuatro filas esten alineadas correctamente.

Answer (score 1):

No funcionan porque el código que muestras tiene serias deficiencias. Menciono algunas de las más evidentes:

- A menos que lo hayas indicado en alguna parte, Bootstrap ofrece, de manera estándar, solo 12 columnas por fila. Tu estás indicando 20, por eso no quedan alineadas.
- A menos que usas otro framework, [Bootstrap 3.x](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) usa la notación `col-xx-n` para las columnas.
- Puedes, por supuesto, cualquier combinación de tamaños de columnas, con la condición que **sumen 12**:

  - 3 + 3 + 3 + 3
  - 4 + 4 + 4
  - 5 + 5 + 2
  - 6 + 4 + 1 + 1
  - etc.
- Además es una buena práctica agregar una clase `container` que envuelva a todo tu contenido.

A continuación, puedes ver tu código funcionando.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="fecha">
        <span class="numero">15</span>&nbsp;
        <span class="mes">JULIO</span>
      </div>
      <div class="texto">
        <p>Cronograma de matr&iacute;culas</p>
        <span>
          Fecha de matr&iacute;culas: 
          15 de julio al 30 de agosto (ordinarias)
        </span>
        <span>
          <br />
          1 de septiembre al 30 de septiembre (extraordinarias)
        </span>
        <span>
          <br />
          <br />
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <h4>Kinder</h4>
      <p>Nacidos entre el 1/09/2012 y el 31/12/2013&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 verde push-down">
      <h3>Requisitos</h3>
      <p>C&eacute;dula de ciudadan&iacute;a</p>
      <span>The Happy Room <br />Mrs Linda</span> 
      <span class="hora">Lunch &amp; Recess 
        <br /> 11:30 AM - 00:30 PM
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 cafe align-center">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
      <p>Donec iaculis</p>
      <span>The Happy Room <br />Mrs Linda</span>
      <span class="hora">Lunch &amp; Recess 
        <br /> 11:30 AM - 00:30 PM
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 amarillo align-center">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
      <p>Donec iaculis</p>
      <span>The Happy Room <br />Mrs Linda</span>
      <span class="hora">Lunch &amp; Recess 
        <br /> 11:30 AM - 00:30 PM
      </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 verde align-center">
      <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
      <p>Donec iaculis</p>
      <span>The Happy Room <br />Mrs Linda</span>
      <span class="hora">Lunch &amp; Recess 
        <br /> 11:30 AM - 00:30 PM
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Viendo tu problema esta en que tienes definida la clase `col5` y por eso no hace el espaciado correspondiente.

Cambia esa clase por `col-xs-5` (moviles), `col-sm-5` (tablets), `col-md-5`(pantallas medianas), `col-lg-5` pantallas largas según el diseño que les vallas a dar, el numero puede cambiar hasta un máximo de 12 y un mínimo de 1

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<b> <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="fecha"><span class="numero">15</span>&nbsp;<span class="mes">JULIO</span></div>
        <div class="texto">
            <p>Cronograma de matr&iacute;culas</p>
            <span>Fecha de matr&iacute;culas: 15 de julio al 30 de agosto (ordinarias)</span><span><br />1 de septiembre al 30 de septiembre (extraordinarias)</span><span><br /><br /></span></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <h4>Kinder</h4>
    <p>Nacidos entre el 1/09/2012 y el 31/12/2013&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-5 verde push-down">
        <h3>Requisitos</h3>
        <p>C&eacute;dula de ciudadan&iacute;a</p>
        <span>The Happy Room <br />Mrs Linda</span> <span class="hora">Lunch &amp; Recess <br /> 11:30 AM - 00:30 PM</span></div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 cafe align-center">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <p>Donec iaculis</p>
        <span>The Happy Room <br />Mrs Linda</span> <span class="hora">Lunch &amp; Recess <br /> 11:30 AM - 00:30 PM</span></div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 amarillo align-center">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <p>Donec iaculis</p>
        <span>The Happy Room <br />Mrs Linda</span> <span class="hora">Lunch &amp; Recess <br /> 11:30 AM - 00:30 PM</span></div>
    <div class="col-sm-5 verde align-center">
        <h3>Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <p>Donec iaculis</p>
        <span>The Happy Room <br />Mrs Linda</span> <span class="hora">Lunch &amp; Recess <br /> 11:30 AM - 00:30 PM</span></div>
</div></b>
```

Answer (score 0):

Todas las filas están formadas por columnas, el 100% del ancho de la fila está formado por 12 columnas, la columna se tratará como unidad de medida para el ancho de los contenedores con Bootstrap.

Esto se aplica a las distintas resoluciones que puede tener el documento.

- xs: resoluciones muy pequeñas como en moviles.
- xm: resoluciones pequeñas como en tablets.
- md: resoluciones de escritorio.
- lg: resoluciones de escritorio más grandes.

por medio de col-resolución-numColumnas asignaremos la clase al contenedor, veamos un ejemplo:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
         Columna 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-9">
         Columna 2
    </div>
</div>
```

Este ejemplo visto desde un móvil cada columna ocupará el 100% del ancho.
Si lo vemos desde una tablet cada columna ocupará el 50%.
Y si lo vemos desde un ordenador se verá la columna 2 que ocupa mucho más que la columna 1